# Stop on submit form refreshing page

Tags: php, ajax, forms, refresh

I am having a problem, since my website reloads each time somemone submit a form.

It's a wide scroll, so i just found also another solution, but gives me an error.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];


if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
unset($_SESSION['sent']);
header('Location: index.php#5'); 
}
?>
```

FORM CODE:

```
<form class="demo-form" name ="demo-form" data-parsley-validate method="post" action="submit.php" >
            <ul>
                <li class="js-hide-label">
                    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="name" name="name" data-parsley-trigger="change" required tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['post']['name']) ? $_SESSION['post']['name'] : ''); ?>" >
                </li>
                <li class="js-hide-label">
                    <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" data-parsley-trigger="change"  name="email"  autocomplete="off" required tabindex="2" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['post']['email']) ? $_SESSION['post']['email'] : ''); ?>">
                </li>
                <li class="js-hide-label">
                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Message…" id="message" name="message" tabindex="3" required data-parsley-trigger="keyup" textarea id="message" data-parsley-minlength="20" data-parsley-maxlength="100" data-parsley-minlength-message = "Come on! You need to enter at least a 20 caracters long comment.." data-parsley-validation-threshold="10"><?php echo (isset($_SESSION['post']['message']) ? $_SESSION['post']['message'] : ''); ?></textarea>
                </li>
                               <input   class="btn btn-default"type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
            </ul>
                          <?php echo isset($success)?$success:''; ?>

        </form>
```

As you can see, adding a POSSIBLE SOLUTION with `header('Location: index.php#5');` makes my website come back to the contact form (not exactly what I wanted, but helps a bit), but it breaks the `$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';`.

Is there any easy way to do it (using my original code) with AJAX? Since I am not used to work with scripts.

In the other hand, could be a solution on display `$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';` and make the function `header('Location: index.php#5');` work on the same form?

Answer (score 0):

Use header and redirect the page.

```
header("Location:your_page.php");
```

You can redirect to same page or different page.

or

```
<?php
session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];


if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{

unset($_SESSION['sent']);
header('Location: index.php?msg=sucess'); 
}

if ( isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 'sucess' )
{
$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
}
```

Comment: AS you can see I added the header to redirect to the #5th page, but when I add it, the success message dissappears

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to post data if you don't want to refresh the page.

See documentation here

[$.post documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Or

[Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

**By using session :**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{       
   unset($_SESSION['sent']);

   $_SESSION['thanks_msg'] = 'Thank You';

   header('Location: index.php#5'); 
}
?>
```

On index.php file :-

check if the $_SESSION['thanks_msg'] is set or not, if set then displaythat session msg.

**By using GET method :-**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
  $success='Thank you!';
  unset($_SESSION['sent']);
  header('Location: index.php?msg='.$success); 
}
?>
```

on index.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    echo $_GET['msg'];
}
```

**EDIT :-**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
  $success='Thank you!';
  unset($_SESSION['sent']);
  header('Location: index.php?msg='.$success); 
}
?>
```

on index.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    echo $_GET['msg'];
}
```

Comment: The first one breaks my form (completely), and the 2nd one, on submit makes the whole form break also, and adds this to my url: http://localhost/web/index.php?msg=<h1>Thank You!</h1>

Comment: Happens exactly the same, it adds to url a thank you message, and breaks my form design, does not appear any content, but the form still working. Otherwhise, I am using the first code with the function of $success='Thank you!' on the top of index.php, so I add both as this: 

if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
  $success='Thank you!';
  unset($_SESSION['sent']);
  header('Location: index.php?msg='.$success); 
}
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    echo $_GET['msg'];
}
?>

Comment: Sure! I mean the form sends me the e-mail, so the problem comes on usability, when the user does not know if he sended the form, because he does not get any feedback. That's what I mean on "the form works".